# How to create a table in a reactive object in Shiny

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, reactive

I am trying to initialize a reactive data.frame in Shiny. I think I'm almost there, but it's not working quite as expected.

Below is a very simple app that I'll just use for explanation purposes. Essentially, the values in the table should change according to the sliderInput. And while they appear to do that, the table output doesn't look like I would a data.frame table to look like in r. Instead of the normal appearance, it outputs only one column (with the heading "data").

I don't think I've fully understand how the reactive() object works, and would appreciate any help in how to initialize a table within a reactive object. Thanks!

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tableOutput("first"),
  sliderInput("num","choose num",1,10,1)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # t1 = (as.data.frame(forecast %>% filter(Date==Sys.Date()-21) %>% group_by(Resort,Date) %>% summarise(`Powder Total` = sum(Snow))))
  # t1=t1[order(t1$`Powder Total`,decreasing=TRUE),][1:5,]

  # output$first = renderTable({
  #   t1[1,]
  #   })

  test = reactive({
    d1 = as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=2,ncol = 2))
    names(d1)=c("col1","col2")
    d1$col1=input$num
    d1$col2=input$num+1
  })

  output$first=renderTable({
    test()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because `reactive()` does not return a data frame but returns a vector of length one. Use `reactiveValues()` instead.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tableOutput("first"),
  sliderInput("num","choose num",1,10,1)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # t1 = (as.data.frame(forecast %>% filter(Date==Sys.Date()-21) %>% group_by(Resort,Date) %>% summarise(`Powder Total` = sum(Snow))))
  # t1=t1[order(t1$`Powder Total`,decreasing=TRUE),][1:5,]

  # output$first = renderTable({
  #   t1[1,]
  #   })

  tableData = reactiveValues(d1 = as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=2,ncol = 2)))

  observeEvent(input$num, {

    temp = tableData$d1
    names(temp)=c("col1","col2")
    temp$col1=input$num
    temp$col2=input$num+1

    tableData$d1 = temp

  })

  test = reactive({
    d1 = as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=2,ncol = 2))
    names(d1)=c("col1","col2")
    d1$col1=input$num
    d1$col2=input$num+1
  })

  output$first=renderTable({
    tableData$d1
  })

  observe({print(test())})        # check console output
  observe({print(tableData$d1)})  # check console output

  observe({print(is.data.frame(test()))
           print(is.data.frame(tableData$d1))

    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I've included a few observe calls for you to see that `test()` is not a dataframe.

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! Just to make sure I've understood it properly, the reason it didn't work is because reactive() can only have, at max, a vector of length one. reactiveValues() on the other hand, can have an unlimited length, which then allows it to create a data frame (because all a dataframe is is multiple vectors)?

Comment: That is correct. A data frame is a list of vectors.

Comment: You can also have multiple data frames in ````reactiveValues()```` like so ````reactiveValues(df1 = mtcars, df2 = iris)````